# Proof of the uniform continuity of $\sin$ function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Is it correct to take $\delta = 2\pi$ to conclude on the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition?:

$\forall$$\epsilon$>0, $\exists$$\delta$>0, $\forall x,y \in$ Dom(function) 
$|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon.$

In my opinion, with $2\pi$ you cover all possible cases,  but I don't know if it's correct ; I need to know if I'm wrong and why (Sorry about the typing, i'm not used to TEX format).

Comment: No, it is wrong. Take $x = 0$ and $y = \pi/2$ and $\epsilon = 0.1$. What do you find?

Comment: You need to edit the title of your question as well. One would never say "uniform continuity of some function" but "uniform continuity of some function *on some set*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Mean Value Theorem here: $|\sin x - \sin y| = |\cos c||x-y| \le |x-y|$ . Thus for a given $\epsilon > 0$, you can take $\delta = \epsilon$, then this inequality implies uniform continuity of $\sin x$. In commenting about your proof, it is wrong as the comment above provided a counter example...